Exit code 2147483651 (0x80000003) in VS2022/.NET 8/SharpDX and no DirectX Debugging
I'm working on a DirectX project using SharpDX and .NET 8 in Windows 11.
Application exits with error code (0x80000003) whenever there's an issue with the DirectX code, instead of providing me with DirectX debugging output.  I even get this error when I exit the application "gracefully".  Because of the lack of useful debugging output, I am left to blindly try and correct the code.  I am very familiar with SharpDX and all of its quirks but VS2022 doesn't even raise an exception; the application simply exits with (0x80000003).  The only debugging output I can
get is from SharpDX itself when identifying COM objects which haven't been released.
I have:

Reinstalled VS2022
Reinstalled "Graphics Tools" (DirectX Debug Layer)
Installed the latest Windows 11 SDK

I realize that (0x80000003) is a very general error that can occur under a wide variety of circumstances, but I am hoping someone here might be able to suggest a solution.

You need to give more details especially an example code, and where someone else can reproduce the problem

0x80000003 (E_INVALIDARG) is not so common, 0x80070057 (also E_INVALIDARG...) is indeed very common (last one is a developer error, calling some function with wrong args). What do you mean exactly by "application exits with (0x80000003)"?  Is it a crash?

Hi Simon, thanks for your input. When I say "application exits with (0x80000003)", i mean that if I incorrectly declare something in SharpDX (which has strange behaviour which isn't explicitly expressed in the code editor tooltips.  For example, some constructors say that they expect a Factory object, but in reality they need a Factory1 and nothing else, not a Factory2, 3 , 4 etc.), when that code runs, the application exits with that error.  No exception or other information about the error.  I also get it when I explicitly exit by pressing ESC, doing cleanup and then call Application.Exit.

0x80000003 is STATUS_BREAKPOINT.  The unmanaged code in DirectX is trying to tell you something, but it can't because unmanaged debugging is not enabled.  Fix that with Project > Properties > Debug, tick "Enable native code debugging".  Turn on the symbol server if it isn't enabled yet so the stack trace gets useful.  Look at the Output window for a diagnostic message.

@HansPassant Thank you very much, Hans.  I am admittedly perplexed as to why the D3D debugging layer isn't sending any output.  The Direct3D device has been created with  DeviceCreationFlags.Debug.  I'll do as you suggest and see how that goes.  Thank you again.

@HansPassant Thank you kindly, Hans.  D3D Debug layer is now providing verbose output.  Prior to VS 2022, I always had native debugging enabled, because it was right there, under Project -> Properties.  In 2022 they've tucked it away...thanks again!  I'm very pleased. +1 to you, mate.
